# Create versions in eclipse using local history

Tags: eclipse, version-control, versioning

Is it possible to leverage eclipses built-in local history to create and save versions. I find local history very useful, but if I could restore the whole project to a previous state that would be even better. I've considered using version management, but it seems unnecessary as I am the only person working on my project. And I could really benefit from the ability to name my (local history) versions instead of having to go by date.

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going through a lot of hassle just to avoid version control.  Instead!  Use a local version of subversion for all your version control needs.

You do not need to host a server.  It will use the filesystem only!  Use subclipse or subversive to integrate into eclipse.

A tutorial how to set it up(takes less than 5 minutes):

http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/setup-svn-local-repository-step-by-step/

Comment: Thanks! You are very insightful, this is just what I needed.